# How to divide contours?

Tags: python, image, opencv

I want to detect objects in an image and measure the distance between them. This works as long as the objects do not come too close. Unfortunately the lighting of the image is not optimal, so it looks like objects are touching although they are not. I am trying to determine the distance with the help of a line, which represents the object. Problem is that as soon as the object contours join, I cannot determine the lines which represent the objects, so no distance can be calculated.

Input Image:

[image]

Code:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

#import image
img = cv2.imread('img.png', 0)

#Thresh
_, thresh = cv2.threshold(img, 200, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)

#Finding the contours in the image
_, contours, _ = cv2.findContours(thresh, cv2.RETR_TREE, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)

#Convert img to RGB and draw contour
img = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_GRAY2RGB)
cv2.drawContours(img, contours, -1, (0,0,255), 2)

#Object1
v = np.matrix([[0], [1]])
rect = cv2.minAreaRect(contours[0])

#determine angle
if rect[1][0] > rect[1][1]:
    ang = (rect[2] + 90)* np.pi / 180
else:
    ang = rect[2]* np.pi / 180
rot = np.matrix([[np.cos(ang), -np.sin(ang)],[np.sin(ang), np.cos(ang)]])
rv = rot*v

#draw angle line
lineSize = max(rect[1])*0.45                #length of line
p1 = tuple(np.array(rect[0] - lineSize*rv.T)[0].astype(int))
p2 = tuple(np.array(rect[0] + lineSize*rv.T)[0].astype(int))
cv2.line(img, p1, p2, (255,0,0), 2)

#Object2
if len(contours) > 1:
    rect = cv2.minAreaRect(contours[1])

    #determine angle
    if rect[1][0] > rect[1][1]:
        ang = (rect[2] + 90)* np.pi / 180
    else:
        ang = rect[2]* np.pi / 180
    rot = np.matrix([[np.cos(ang), -np.sin(ang)],[np.sin(ang), np.cos(ang)]])
    rv = rot*v

    #draw angle line
    lineSize = max(rect[1])*0.45                #length of line
    p1 = tuple(np.array(rect[0] - lineSize*rv.T)[0].astype(int))
    p2 = tuple(np.array(rect[0] + lineSize*rv.T)[0].astype(int))
    cv2.line(img, p1, p2, (255,0,0), 2)


#save output img
cv2.imwrite('output_img.png', img)
```

Output Image:

[image]

This works fine but as soon as I use an image with joined contours this happens:

[image]
[image]

Is there a way to divide contours or maybe a workaround?

**Edit**

Thanks to the suggestion of B.M. I tried if erosion is a solution but unfortunately new problems come into place. It does not seem to be possible to find a balance between erosion and thresholding/contours.

Examples:

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: automatically detect, that a split is necessary by testing that not all points on your computed line are within the contour. Then you could play a bit with convexity defects, distance transform etc.

Comment: That is a good idea, will try it out

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about if you first search for contours and check if there are in fact two. If there is only one you could make a loop to erode and search for contours on the eroded image until you get two contours. When the event happens make a black bounding box that is bigger for the amount of kernel used on the eroded image and draw in on the "original image which will physically divide and create 2 contours. Then apply your code to the resulting image. Maybe you can upload the images you have the most dificulty with before processing? Hope it helps a bit or gives you a new idea. Cheers!

Example code:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

img = cv2.imread('cont.png')
gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
_, threshold = cv2.threshold(gray, 200, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)
_, contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(threshold,cv2.RETR_TREE,cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE)
k = 2

if len(contours)==1:
    for i in range (0,1000):
        kernel = np.ones((1,k),np.uint8)
        erosion = cv2.erode(threshold,kernel,iterations = 1)
        _, contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(erosion,cv2.RETR_TREE,cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE)
        if len(contours) == 1:
            k+=1
        if len(contours) == 2:
            break
        if len(contours) > 2:
            print('more than one contour')

x,y,w,h = cv2.boundingRect(contours[0])
cv2.rectangle(threshold,(x-k,y-k),(x+w+k,y+h+k), 0, 1)
_, contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(threshold,cv2.RETR_TREE,cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE)
cv2.drawContours(img, contours, -1, (0,0,255), 2)

#Object1
v = np.matrix([[0], [1]])
rect = cv2.minAreaRect(contours[0])

#determine angle
if rect[1][0] > rect[1][1]:
    ang = (rect[2] + 90)* np.pi / 180
else:
    ang = rect[2]* np.pi / 180
rot = np.matrix([[np.cos(ang), -np.sin(ang)],[np.sin(ang), np.cos(ang)]])
rv = rot*v

#draw angle line
lineSize = max(rect[1])*0.45                #length of line
p1 = tuple(np.array(rect[0] - lineSize*rv.T)[0].astype(int))
p2 = tuple(np.array(rect[0] + lineSize*rv.T)[0].astype(int))
cv2.line(img, p1, p2, (255,0,0), 2)

#Object2
if len(contours) > 1:
    rect = cv2.minAreaRect(contours[1])

    #determine angle
    if rect[1][0] > rect[1][1]:
        ang = (rect[2] + 90)* np.pi / 180
    else:
        ang = rect[2]* np.pi / 180
    rot = np.matrix([[np.cos(ang), -np.sin(ang)],[np.sin(ang), np.cos(ang)]])
    rv = rot*v

    #draw angle line
    lineSize = max(rect[1])*0.45                #length of line
    p1 = tuple(np.array(rect[0] - lineSize*rv.T)[0].astype(int))
    p2 = tuple(np.array(rect[0] + lineSize*rv.T)[0].astype(int))
    cv2.line(img, p1, p2, (255,0,0), 2)


#save output img

cv2.imshow('img', img)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Result:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can use erosion techniques like [`cv2.erode`](https://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/doc/py_tutorials/py_imgproc/py_morphological_ops/py_morphological_ops.html) provides. After

```
from cv2 import erode
import numpy as np    
kernel = np.ones((5,25),dtype=np.uint8) # this must be tuned 

im1=erode(im0,kernel)
```

You obtain a image (`im0` is your second image) where bright zones are shrank :

[image]

Now you will be able to measure a distance, even if the effect of erosion must be took in account.

Comment: OpenCV also provides [morphological transformations](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d9/d61/tutorial_py_morphological_ops.html). Probably better to use that, as opposed to dragging in yet another massive third party library.

Comment: Thanks for your Answer. With the use of erosion new problems come into place. Some of the object contours are not recognized properly anymore (for example only half the object is detected). And still on some images the overlapping finds place. It does not seem to be possible to find a balance between erosion, thresholding and contour overlapping. In addition the background gets eroded too and at some point becomes part of threshold.

Comment: Try applying dilation immediately after erosion but experiment with different kernel sizes to perform the operations. For example, try 3x3 for erosion with 5x5 for dilation or 5x5 for erosion with 3x3 for dilation.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can adopt a watershed binary segmentation approach (I would suggest ITK for this).
A combination of :

- distance map calculation
- Reconstruction by dilation
- Regional Maxima
- Morphological Watershed From Markers
  will lead to following separation :
  [image: separated]

Once separation done you can :

- extract contour points
- compute associated polygonal approximation
- compute exact distance between two particules
  (geometric part could use boost geometry library for example but this is a c++ library)

You could also use a pure geometric/morphological approach :

- extract contour points
- compute associated polygonal approximation
  [image: polygonal approximation]
- compute associated voronoi diagram (which can be considered as a skeleton for the shape)
  [image: voronoi diagram]
- compute thickness associated to each branch of previous skeleton
- make cuts at min thickness sections
  [image: image cuts]

Regards,

Comment: Hey, your approach looks very promising. I will look into it when I have time. Thanks

Comment: I am following your approach to voronoi diagram. I'm stuck at the polygonal approximation step. Could you please provide info of how I could get into it?

Comment: Hi Artur, I use the boost polygon library to proceed with voronoi diagram computation : https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_68_0/libs/polygon/doc/voronoi_diagram.htm

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem like this:

1. take length of last image's objects (or make a factor if it is your first image)
2. build two thresholds for every object
3. erase everything below/above in the threshold (with help of 1.). Basically I started counting from lower edge of object up to its length (In threshold array).
4. Make a split and share it for both objects as border of contour.
5. Find new contours.

Counting the threshold array upwards (for second object) to find lowest point looks like this:

```
    else:
        del lineSize_list[-1], ang_list[-1]       #delete wrong values from Size and Angle lists
        z = 0
        thresh2 = np.copy(thresh)
        for x in thresh2[::-1]:                   #check threshold backwards for positive values
            for e in x:
                if e > 0:
                    break
            z += 1
            if e > 0:
                 - first positive value found in threshold (edge of object)
                 - add object length to this position
                 - make a cut in threshold (this will be the break for new contours)
                 - use threshold to find contours ....
```

This works for measuring the distance between both objects. The Result looks similar to kavko's. I will accept his answer because he invested time.

This is a simplified clunky solution. It only works because I can cut the threshold array in two. It would be awesome if there is a more professional way to divide contours. Anyway, thanks alot.

Answer (score 0):

You can apply a cluster analysis (k-means for example) at all the points of the unique contour with 2 as number of clusters.

```
from sklearn.cluster import KMeans

array = np.vstack(contours)
all_points = array.reshape(array.shape[0], array.shape[2])
kmeans = KMeans(n_clusters=2, random_state=0, n_init = 50).fit(all_points)
new_contours = [all_points[kmeans.labels_==i] for i in range(2)]*
```